# show default page name when page redirected

Tags: asp.net

i want to show a user whole asp.net project default page URL in browser. not shows redirected pages name.
It is possible or not? if it possible so please provide working examples with code explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on the default page for when to redirect would likely be a solution to preserve the name of the original page though you may have to add logic on the redirected page to not have a title in this case.